# Create a new array from 2 arrays -- with conditions

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 arrays that I need to join together, with some conditions.

Array 1 is an array of objects that contains user ID, usernames.

Array 2 contains other data that belongs to the user ID's in the first array. The ID in the 'sentBy' parameter matches the id in the array 1.

I've been scratching my head all night to get at this state, and I'm still scratching it to find a good solution to this problem. Any help very appreciated.

Array 1:

```
[ { id: 1,
    username: 'test2' },
  { id: 2,
    username: 'test3' },
  { id: 3,
    username: 'test4' } ]
```

Array 2:

```
[ { sentBy: 1,
    message: 'hey',
    createdAt: 'date' },
  { sentBy: 3,
    message: 'hey2',
    createdAt: 'date' },
  { sentBy: 1,
    message: 'hey3',
    createdAt: 'date' } ]
```

End result should look like:

```
[ 
  { 
    id: 1,
    username: 'test2',
    offlineMessages: 
    [ 
      { message: 'hey', createdAt: 'date' },
      { message: 'hey3', createdAt: 'date' }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    username: 'test3',
    offlineMessages: [] 
   },
  { 
    id: 3,
    username: 'test4',
    offlineMessages: 
    [ 
      { message: 'hey2', createdAt: 'date' }
    ] 
   } 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution. This will modify the `users` array in-place.

```
var users = [ { id: 759141,
    username: 'test2' },
  { id: 759142,
    username: 'test3' },
  { id: 759143,
    username: 'test4' } ];

var messages = [ { sentBy: 759141,
    message: 'hey',
    createdAt: 'date' },
  { sentBy: 759143,
    message: 'hey2',
    createdAt: 'date' },
  { sentBy: 759141,
    message: 'hey3',
    createdAt: 'date' } ];

var usersMap = {};
var user;

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
    user = users[i];
    usersMap[user.id] = user;
    user.offlineMessages = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
    user = usersMap[messages[i].sentBy];

    if (user) {
        user.offlineMessages.push({
            message: messages[i].message,
            createdAt: messages[i].createdAt
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, and quick, good job, i'll try to make sure I understand completely well after I've rested a little! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I just changed it a bit for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
var getMessageById = function (userId) { 
    return array2.filter(function (obj) { 
        return obj.sentBy == userId; 
    }); 
};
```

It'll return all messages for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I like to work with hash tables..

```
result = []; // -> Should be {} ! Read comments below!
for(var i in array1) {
  result[array1[i].id] = array1[i];
  result[array1[i].id].offlineMessages = [];
}

for(var i in array2) {
  result[array2[i].sendBy].offlineMessages.push( {
    message: array2[i].message,
    createdAt: array2[i].createdAt
  });
}
```

Comment: I would write: result = {} because you don't use it as an array.

Comment: I agree that {} would be the proper syntax. However, {} says object to me while calling the result a 'named array'. Is there a disadvantage to use []?

Comment: The array would expand to hold all ids even if they are not used. If an id is 10000 you get 10000 elements in the array.

Comment: You are 100% correct! I thought that this didn't happen with i.e. result["123"] but it does..  Shame on me!